# Using "esm" in VSCode's NodeJs Debugger

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

I am using Vscode.

I have a js file filled with a dozen+ class definitions which I wanted to be available in another jsfile.
So I used es6 imports in my other file, main.js

```
//main.js
import * as Helper from './helperClasses.js';
var myDoggy = new Helper.Pet("Fido");
```

But that wouldn't run with node, so I installed 'esm' with npm, and made a file called server.js, in which I added

```
//server.js
require = require("esm")(module/*, options*/)
module.exports = require("./main.js")
```

Now that runs with the code runner extension, or from a cmd window with the '-r esm' args (i.e. `node -r esm server.js`). But in the vsCode debugger, I get the following error:

```
import * as helper from './helperClasses.js';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```

I tried changing the configuration settings in launch.json as follows, but that did not work:

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\game.js",
            "args": ["-r","esm","server.js"]
        }
    ]
```

I went and changed the .js extensions to .mjs, but then intellisense stopped working...

Is there something I'm missing? This is my first time trying to use Node and I'm just trying to easily import some helper functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your launch.json has to be

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\server.js",
        "args": ["-r","esm"]
    }
]
```

The path of the server.js has to be accurate though. For example, in case, if it is under folder 'app' make it 
          `"program": "${workspaceFolder}\\app\\server.js"`

Let know if it helps or if the issues persits.

Comment: Doesn't works: `import express from 'express';` `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: David Figaterner's answer works below, but this one doesn't.

Answer (score 27):

I had a problem with the accepted answer. Using `runtimeArgs` worked better:

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "name": "import-test-files",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/scripts/import-test-files.js",
            "runtimeArgs": ["-r", "esm"]
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

thats one works for me:

```
"configurations": [
    {
      "type": "pwa-node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ],
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\index.js",
      "runtimeArgs": ["--experimental-modules"]
    }
  ]
```